# Find all nearest zip codes with lat and long from a particular latitude and longitude in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, google-maps

I've a database table in which there are 4 columns.

```
1. id
2. person_name
3. country
4. zip_code
```

Now I want all the zip codes with their real latitude and longitude which come in a given radius of 10 mile from a given lat long.

suppose my latitude and longitudes are **(19.24947300,72.85681400)** and distance is 10 mile, then what SQL query should I make to return all nearest zip codes and their lat longs.

I only have the following query

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() 
/ 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon – lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 *
1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `members` HAVING `distance`<=’10’ ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

But it requires the lat longs of all zip codes in the table but I want them in run time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by

> But it requires the lat longs of all zip codes in the table but I want them in run time.

Since you want a SQL query, I assume that you have a table with every zip code's latitude and longitude.

You probably shouldn't do all that math in your SQL query. I would first pull every zip code that is in a 10 mile x 10 mile square centered in your queried position and then, if you really need just those that are positively in a 10 mile radius, check in your program (I assume you are using PHP, since you have variables starting with $).

```
SELECT zip, latitude, longitude FROM zip_positions
WHERE latitude > 19.24947300 - DISTANCE and latitude < 19.24947300 + DISTANCE
AND longitude > 72.85681400 - DISTANCE and longitude < 72.85681400 + DISTANCE
```

where DISTANCE is a rough equivalent to 10 miles in latitude/longitude that you would have to calculate.

Then you would, if you need it, check in PHP (or whatever language you're using) every result to see if it is indeed less than 10 miles from the point queried. I can't help you as to how to precisely convert latitude and longitude to distance in miles.

Comment: This works but only roughly ...  you really want to calculate distance between the lat/lon to lat/lons in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this abandoned question was resolved, but let me share my opinions here in case someone else is wrestling with this one. I present 3 options for letting closet zip from DB using lat long as the lookup:

**DB LOOKUP OPTION 1 (QUICK AND DIRTY):**

SET @lat = 41.675868;
SET @long = -73.864484;
SET @tol = .05;

SELECT * FROM `mytable`.ZipCodes 
WHERE latitude >= @lat AND latitude <= @lat  + @tol
AND longitude >= @long AND longitude <= @long  + @tol
ORDER BY (ABS(latitude-longitude) - ABS(@lat-@long)) ASC
LIMIT 1

**OPTION #2 (VARIATION ON #1)**

$qry = "SELECT zipcode,cityname,stateabbr        FROM `dealer-site`.ZipCodes        WHERE (latitude >= {$lat} AND latitude <= {$lat}+1)  AND (ABS(longitude) >= ABS({$long}) AND ABS(longitude) < ABS({$long})+1)        ORDER BY latitude ASC       LIMIT 1”;

**OPTION #3 BEST METHOD CALCULATE . I WOULD TRY TO USE THIS:**

SET @latitude = 41.675868;
SET @longitude = -73.864484;

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *,
            (((ACOS(SIN((@latitude * PI() / 180)) * 
               SIN((`latitude` * PI() / 180)) + COS((@latitude  * PI() / 180)) * COS((`latitude` * PI() / 180)) * COS(((@longitude - `longitude`) * PI() / 180)))) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) AS distance
    FROM
        `mytable`.ZipCodes) ZipCodes
WHERE
    distance <= 5
LIMIT 10

PHP MYSQL (LEGACY CALL) :

```
           $qry = "SELECT zipcode
            FROM (SELECT *,
                (((ACOS(SIN(({$lat} * PI() / 180)) * 
                SIN((`latitude` * PI() / 180)) + COS(({$lat}  * PI() / 180)) * COS((`latitude` * PI() / 180)) * 
                COS((({$long} - `longitude`) * PI() / 180)))) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) 
            AS distance
            FROM
            `MyDB`.ZipCodes) ZipCodes
            WHERE distance <= 5
            LIMIT 1
    ";
```